# Django:Bug reporting app

Tags: django

Is there any Django bug reporting app which can be integrated easily into already built Django website and which lets site users to report bugs?

Comment: It's not a Django app, but depending on your needs, something like [UserVoice](http://www.uservoice.com/) or [Get Satisfaction](https://getsatisfaction.com/) may do what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My experience with user reported bugs is not satisfactory.

After some years my decision is to make everyhing fail loudly and use [Sentry](https://github.com/dcramer/django-sentry) to log it.

Sentry is a great app. It was created by dcramer, a guy working on disqus (they use it too).

I know this is not what you're directly looking for, but might be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

As usual [Django Packages](http://www.djangopackages.com/) is the best stop for an overview of existing apps.

In your case make sure to check the apps listed in the [Feedback-Grid](http://www.djangopackages.com/grids/g/feedback/).